# Prevent a program from creating files in a users home directory

Tags: windows, file-management

I run an engineering program for class, Quartus 2. The *issue* i am having is that every time i launch the program, it creates 10 bitmap files in my home directory.

[image]

This is not so much of a problem, it just makes my OCD hurt :(
I can delete them without affecting anything, but every time the program is launched it recreates them, and there is nothing in the program (that i have found) that stops these files from being created.

Is there anything i can do to prevent this program, or any profram from creating files like this in my home folder?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't store any other bitmaps in the root of your home directory AND the app creates these bitmaps upon startup then you could use a batch script to open the program.
My batch scripting is a little rusty but possibly something like this:

```
@echo off
start "path\to\your\application.exe"

REM Wastes a few second to allow bitmaps to be created
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 6

REM Change to home directory
cd path\to\your\home\directory
del *.bmp /f /q

REM Close Batch Window
exit
```

If you do have bitmaps in there then maybe change the del line to `del qms*.bmp` and that will only remove bitmaps whose name starts with qms.